# ListView displays nothing

Tags: android, listview

I would like to send selected item from listview to another listview with sharedprefences. I can save item but cannot see this item another listview. **Activity class**

```
TextView textUrun = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textUrun);
            TextView textFiyat = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textFiyat);
            String yemek = textUrun.getText().toString();
            String fiyat = textFiyat.getText().toString();
            DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider(yemek,fiyat);
            list.add(dataProvider);
            String jsonurun = gson.toJson(list);
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("yemekbilgi", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("yemek",jsonurun);
            editor.apply();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Listeye Kaydedildi",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

This is list class which should display items.**Listele1**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("urun1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    List<DataProvider> list;
    String jsonurun = sharedPreferences.getString("liste1", "");
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    DataProvider[] providers = gson.fromJson(jsonurun, DataProvider[].class);
    list = Arrays.asList(providers);
    listDataAdapter = new ListDataAdapter(getApplicationContext(), list);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.liste1);
    listView.setAdapter(listDataAdapter);
```

Finally,this is **Adapter Class**

```
public class ListDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
List list = new ArrayList();

public ListDataAdapter(@NonNull Context context,List<DataProvider> list) {
    super(context, R.layout.be_layout, list);
}

static class LayoutHandler{
    TextView ad,fiyat;
}

@Override
public void add(@Nullable Object object) {
    super.add(object);
    list.add(object);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    LayoutHandler layoutHandler;
    if (view == null){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_layout,parent,false);
        layoutHandler = new LayoutHandler();
        layoutHandler.ad = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textUrun);
        layoutHandler.fiyat = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textFiyat);
        view.setTag(layoutHandler);
    }
    else
        layoutHandler = (LayoutHandler) view.getTag();
    DataProvider dataProvider = (DataProvider) this.getItem(position);
    layoutHandler.ad.setText(dataProvider.getAd());
    layoutHandler.fiyat.setText(dataProvider.getFiyat());
    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: put your list `List<DataProvider>` to adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: you pass empty list, see my answer to fix yours

Comment: You don't need to override add method of ArrayAdapter, or keep an Arraylist field in it

Answer (score 1):

You passed in a List, but you never assigned it.

```
public class ListDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DataProvider> {
    List<DataProvider> list;  // don't assign here 

    public ListDataAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource,List<DataProvider> list) {
        super(context, resource, list);
        this.list = list;   // see here 
    }
```

It's worth pointing out, though, that you could also not do the above and entirely remove `list`, `add()`, and `getItem()`, `getCount()` definitions, then it'll likely work.

Any usage of `list.get(position)` should instead be `getItem(position)`

Answer (score 0):

```
list = new ArrayList<DataProvider>();
gson = new Gson();
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("yemekbilgi", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String yemek = sharedPreferences.getString("yemek","");
Type type = new TypeToken<List<DataProvider>>(){}.getType();
list = gson.fromJson(yemek,type);
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.liste1);
listDataAdapter = new ListDataAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.child_layout,list);
listView.setAdapter(listDataAdapter);
```

Comment: `new ArrayList<DataProvider>();`  isn't necessary since you're loading from json anyway

Comment: agreed @cricket_007

Comment: make sure `String yemek = sharedPreferences.getString("yemek","");` has value or valid json

Answer (score 0):

```
    list = new ArrayList<DataProvider>();
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.liste1);
    listDataAdapter = new ListDataAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.child_layout,list);
    gson = new Gson();

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("yemekbilgi", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String yemek = sharedPreferences.getString("yemek","");
    Type type = new TypeToken<List<DataProvider>>(){}.getType();
    list.addAll(gson.fromJson(yemek,type));
    listView.setAdapter(listDataAdapter);
    listDataAdapter.notitifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Don't reassign the list object after you create the adapter unless you want to break the adapter